# Switching Emacs server's socket without leaving existing emacs gui

Tags: spacemacs, emacsclient, emacs-daemon

I would like to switch between emacs socket without leaving the GUI. I am able to start two emacs daemon session by doing the following:

In xterm1:

```
emacs --daemon="one"
```

In xterm2:

```
emacs --daemon="two"
```

By doing this, I can group all the file buffers and ansi-term by projects in each emacs server. However, are there any way to switch between daemon one and daemon two (the help page use the term "socket") within the Emacs without leaving the GUI?